# python - How to grep for numbers from log file and do summing

Tags: python

I have a log file with the following strings:

```
2013-09-10 12:29:06 C9 T3 Update:555 Interfaces: 100 nodes: 0 ports: 0 flows: 106677
2013-09-10 12:30:07 C9 T3 Update:555 Interfaces: 100 nodes: 0 ports: 0 flows: 106281
2013-09-10 12:31:07 C9 T3 Update:555 Interfaces: 100 nodes: 0 ports: 0 flows: 108252
2013-09-10 12:32:06 C9 T3 Update:555 Interfaces: 100 nodes: 0 ports: 0 flows: 106650
2013-09-10 12:33:05 C9 T3 Update:555 Interfaces: 100 nodes: 0 ports: 0 flows: 49734
```

I would like to write a script to read through the file and grep only for the # of flows (e.g. 106677) and then do a sum on them.  Any ideas on best approach?  I should first try to strip only the # of flows and write to a file and then do sum?

Answer (score 0):

What about using `csv` module:

```
import csv

with open('logfile') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ")
    print sum(int(line[-1]) for line in reader)
```

prints: `477594` for your example data.